# My Parallel loop does not improve performance

Tags: c#, winforms, parallel-processing

I am using parallel loop for Improving performance in loading my charts which I have called in Parallel loop.

Load Chart method has large code and Which I want to execute in parallel but When I was executing It doesn't show me difference in parallel execution and sequential execution.

Both Parallel and sequential process taking same time for execution.

My Parallel loop code is as below.

```
List<Chart> lstCharts = new List<Chart>();
        Parallel.For(0, givenSampleArray.Length, i =>
            {
                Chart NewChart = new Chart();

                objChart.LoadChart(ref NewChart, givenSampleArray[i], YAxisTable, XPointsValues,
                                   ScaleMinValue, ScaleMaxValue, ref dtNewRowsContainer,
                                   dtExcelData); 
                NewChart.Tag = (i + 1).ToString();
                NewChart.Width = (pnlChart.Width * 49) / (100);


                Legend legend = AddLegend();
                NewChart.Legends.Add(legend);

                lstCharts.Add(NewChart);
            }
        );
```

Comment: Moving an entire operation from one thread to another will not improve performance. The idea is that the operation is split across threads.. not moved entirely to another..

Comment: @SimonWhitehead thanks for commenting. Can you please give me brief idea what should I need to change in code. or any useful link.

Comment: (Also, that code - if run on multiple threads - is *not* threadsafe due to accessing shared *non-threadsafe* resources.)

Comment: Just checking: Does `dtExcelData` relate to Excel or it just named that for for fun?

Comment: how about your ChartControl. are you sure that your chart control can render multiple charts in parallel?

Comment: @DJ I am Collecting charts in one Array. and then one by one Render to the FlowLayotPanel.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov yes, dtExcelData is DataTable which I have read from Excel file and I am doing filtering from dtExcelData.

Answer (score 18):

I note that you do not have a question in your question, so I'll ask some for you:

> Why doesn't my program get faster when I parallelize it?

Nine women can't get together and make a baby in a month. Some operations do not speed up when you parallelize them. This is one of them.

> What characterizes problems that can be solved efficiently through parallelization?

Operations that get faster when you parallelize them have the properties that (1) the problem can easily be divided into as many parts as you want, (2) the smaller problems can be correctly solved independently of each other, and (3) the solutions to the smaller problems can be cheaply combined into a solution to the larger problem.

For example, compare computing a physics simulation with computing a fractal image. Simulations of many interacting bodies are hard to tease apart into sub-problems because all the parts interact. But the first thousand pixels of a fractal do not interact with the second thousand. Fractal calculations are easily parallelized; physics simulations are a lot harder to parallelize. (Though of course it can be done; it's just not easy.)

> Suppose I do have an "embarrassingly parallel" problem to solve. Will making ten threads make it ten times faster?

No. First off, if you want a job to be faster when you parallelize it you need to *saturate the processors*. If you have only four processors then ten threads are making your program *slower*, not *faster*. Second, creating and managing threads has costs, and those costs come out of the bottom line.

Think of threads as drivers and processors as cars. If you have a thousand packages to deliver, one car and one driver, maybe it will take 100 hours. If you hire another driver, you've spent the money on the driver but without an extra car, it's not going to get any faster; it's going to get slower. If you buy four cars, you want four drivers delivering 250 packages each. Will it take 25 hours? Well, how long did it take you to hire those drivers? Threads aren't cheap to allocate; it takes time, and you have to account for that.

And you certainly don't want four cars shared amongst ten drivers each responsible for 100 packages! That's just going to make it slower and more expensive because you're paying for all ten drivers even though at any moment at least six of them are sitting idle waiting for a car to become available.

Summing up: do not attempt to parallelize unless you have an easily parallelizable problem that saturates the processor, where the job is much more expensive than creating a thread, and ensure that there are no more threads than processors. Ideally you want to use tasks instead of threads; the Task Parallel Library is designed to do the work for you of figuring out how many threads to schedule.

Comment: +1 to very nice answer... To add one case that likely covers original question:  "there is only one car in the world that can deliver packages of that type - so no matter how many drivers you have there is still only car to use." Excel would be such car - most likely you can't paralellize access to Excel...